# How to properly implement event for button click and how to change GUI elements on the fly

Tags: python, events, wxpython

I made a small ugly GUI, following some tutorials and reading what I understood on basic WxPython I am working on python 2.6 currently. I managed to get most things to display but I want to basically get the filepath on the filepicker button when I click on the check button but when I attempted to make the bind I get an error saying the object does not have the attribute.

It is more of a basic python issue than Wxpython itself in my opinion I don't know how it wants me to perform the call for the event

Also I would like to eventually change the passed text to green or something or an event but if I try to do anything outside of basicGUI with the elements I fail to properly reference them(things like the panel, etc) so any ideas on how to implement changes to GUI elements would be helpful on top of the button event.

I tried copying an example of someone else using the button event, but it does not work in my implementation because the way I defined the class I think... I need to figure out how to adapt that line of code so it references the object properly.

```
import wx
import ctypes
try:
    ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(True)
except:
    pass


class windowClass(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):

        super(windowClass,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

        self.basicGUI()

    #GUI elements    
    def basicGUI(self):
        panel=wx.Panel(self)
        menu_bar=wx.MenuBar()
        box_sizer=wx.BoxSizer()
        box_sizer.Add(panel, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND) 

        button_text=wx.StaticText(panel, label="Select a file")
        file_button=wx.FilePickerCtrl(panel)
        check_button=wx.Button(panel, label='Check')

        #self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, OnCheckButton(self), check_button)

        a_text=wx.StaticText(panel, label="a file status")
        b_text=wx.StaticText(panel, label="b file status")
        c_text=wx.StaticText(panel, label="c file status")
        passed_text=wx.StaticText(panel, label="passed")

        #set items on the grid
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)
        sizer.Add(button_text, (0, 0))
        sizer.Add(file_button, (0, 2))
        sizer.Add(check_button,(1, 2))
        sizer.Add(a_text,    (2, 0))
        sizer.Add(b_text,    (3, 0))
        sizer.Add(c_text,    (4, 0))
        sizer.Add(passed_text, (2, 1))

        #make border
        border = wx.BoxSizer()
        border.Add(sizer, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        #use sizers
        panel.SetSizerAndFit(border)  
        self.SetSizerAndFit(box_sizer)  
        #show GUI
        self.SetTitle('file check')
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

        def OnCheckButton(self,event):
            print("perform check")   #debug line
            #file_button.GetPath(self)  this probably won't work either as is, 
            #don't know how to pass the button info

app=wx.App()

windowClass(None)

print("passed")

app.MainLoop()
```

at this early stage I expect to click the button and be able to print or do other things... but since it says it is not defined it is sort of an odd error.

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCheckButton(self), check_button)
AttributeError: 'windowClass' object has no attribute 'OnCheckButton'
```

Comment: you have wrong indentations and `OnCheckButton` is not method in class but function inside `basicGUI` so you get error `object has no attribute 'OnCheckButton'`

Comment: BTW: in most GUI framework binding function need "callback" - it means function's name without `()` and arguments. `self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, OnCheckButton, check_button)`. If you use with `()` then it execute `OnCheckButton` at start and assign its result as function executed by button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: you have wrong indentations and `OnCheckButton` is not method in class `windowClass` but normal function inside `basicGUI` so it can't find method `OnCheckButton` in class `windowClass` and you get error `'windowClass' object has no attribute 'OnCheckButton'`

Second: probably in all GUI frameworks (probably in all languages) `Button` needs "callback" - it means function's name without `()` and arguments. When you click button then system will run this function by adding `()`

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCheckButton, check_button)
```

Third: use `self.` in `self.file_button` to have access to this variable in metehod `OnCheckButton` and get path of selected file.

---

Full code:

```
import wx
import ctypes
try:
    ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(True)
except:
    pass


class WindowClass(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WindowClass,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.basicGUI()

    #GUI elements    
    def basicGUI(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        menu_bar = wx.MenuBar()
        box_sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        box_sizer.Add(panel, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND) 

        button_text = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Select a .cpf file")
        self.file_button = wx.FilePickerCtrl(panel)
        check_button = wx.Button(panel, label='Check')

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCheckButton, check_button)

        a_text = wx.StaticText(panel, label="a file status")
        b_text = wx.StaticText(panel, label="b file status")
        c_text = wx.StaticText(panel, label="c file status")
        passed_text = wx.StaticText(panel, label="passed")

        #set items on the grid
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)
        sizer.Add(button_text, (0, 0))
        sizer.Add(self.file_button, (0, 2))
        sizer.Add(check_button,(1, 2))
        sizer.Add(a_text, (2, 0))
        sizer.Add(b_text, (3, 0))
        sizer.Add(c_text, (4, 0))
        sizer.Add(passed_text, (2, 1))

        #make border
        border = wx.BoxSizer()
        border.Add(sizer, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        #use sizers
        panel.SetSizerAndFit(border)  
        self.SetSizerAndFit(box_sizer)  
        #show GUI
        self.SetTitle('file check')
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    # indentations are very important in Python
    def OnCheckButton(self, event): 
        print("perform check")   #debug line
        print(self.file_button.GetPath())

app = wx.App()
WindowClass(None)
print("passed")
app.MainLoop()
```

---

BTW: read [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It suggests how to format code in Python and many people and tools respect these rules.

Comment: thanks, guess I define the class wrong and ended up being a function instead, I will read the style guide, guess it will help when this gets bigger

Comment: I changed code to add `self.file_button` so now `OnCheckButton` can get path for selected file.